# How to find curve which runs through complex points?

Tags: curve-fitting, complex-numbers, exponential, maxima, spiral

I have lists of complex points: orbit of complex point z under [quadratic function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/q-iterations#Forward_iteration)

```
 f(z) = z*z
```

I know that lists are:

- z,  z^2, z^4, z^8, ...
- (r,t), (r^2, 2*t), ..., (r^(2^n), t*2^n)

where :

- r = abs(z)
- t = arg(z)

So I think that these curve will be [exponential spirals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral).

But [my code](https://gitlab.com/adammajewski/invariant_curves_on_the_dynamic_plane/blob/master/s.mac):

```
 GiveParametric(radius,tMin,tMax) := 
 parametric(radius^t*cos(t),radius^t*sin(t),t,tMin,tMax)$

 GivePolar(radius, tMin,tMax) :=  polar(radius^(2^t),t,tMin,tMax)$
```

does not work.

Here is the image of 3 orbits (lists). Each list sould have it's own curve ( function)
[image]

Question :

> How to draw (or find equations of) curves which runs through these points ?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: curve intersects and I belive that they shoud not

Comment: That's the mathematical issue. What do you mean by "does not work" with relation to your code? Also, you should read [ask] and understand what a [mcve] is.

Comment: "does not work" means how to implement in Maxima CAS continous function which goes thru such points. MCVE : in the question is the code and image

Comment: about math issue : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579773/do-two-exponential-spirals-intersect

Comment: It doesn't mean that either. What's wrong with the code that you've got?

Comment: it does not draw continous curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
I have used definition to draw sequence of points joined by lines

```
GiveContOrbit(r0,a0,tMin, tMax, dt ):=
 block(
   [Orbit,a,r,t, b],
   t : tMin,
   b: 2^t,
   a:a0*b,
   r: r0^b,
   z: GiveZ(r,a),
   Orbit:[[realpart(z),imagpart(z)]], 
   for t:tMin thru tMax step dt do
    ( 
        b: 2^t,
    a:a0*b,
    r: r0^b,
    z: GiveZ(r,a), 
    Orbit:endcons([realpart(z),imagpart(z)],Orbit)),
    return(Orbit) 
    )$
```

This in not what I wanted but seems to be a good aproximation. As I see curves intersects.